# RSpec: How to test whether :new is called with correct number of arguments

Tags: rspec

I'd like to test whether my class's initialize method requires two arguments. I have the following:

```
class Game
end
...
require 'game'

describe Game do
  describe '#initialize' do
    it 'requires two players' do
      expect(Game).to respond_to(:new).with(2).arguments
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason the above code passes, even though trying to initialize a `Game` in pry with 2 arguments throws the `ArgumentError` I would expect. How can I write the above test correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it

```
require 'game'

describe Game do
  let(:player1) { Player.new(name: 'Player 1') }
  let(:player2) { Player.new(name: 'Player 2') }

  describe '#initialize' do
    context 'raises ArgumentError when' do
      let(:player3) { Player.new(name: 'Player 3') }

      it "is not called with exactly 2 players" do
        expect { Game.new(player1) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
        expect { Game.new(player1, player2, player3) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)

        expect { Game.new(player1, player2) }.not_to raise_error
      end  
    end
  end
end
```

You need class Player obviously

```
class Player
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name:)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Marko, I was expecting RSpec to have some built-in syntax for addressing this problem, but maybe it doesn't exist....